# ClickOnce redeploys unmodified libraries

Tags: java, dependencies, clickonce

Suppose I have a Java code which depends on lots of libraries.
I use ClickOnce to deploy the application on the clients machine.
When something changes in the code I don't want the dependant libraries to be redeployed.

Current organization is the following:
when the code is changed, it is being compiled, version number increased and lots of jar files within one folder are copied to the distribution folder with the appropriate version. Later the application manifest chooses the latest version and deploys the application COPIYNG all the libraries.

*Main question:* Is it possible to separate the libs which never change with the custom code?

I'm quite new to ClickOnce, searched for MSDN and Googled a little, but failed. So links to the ClickOnce dependency management tutorials will be highly appreciated, thanks!

P.S. ClickOnce for Java code sounds ugly but it was strict political desicision, sorry.